# Email not triggering

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jakarta-mail

I want to trigger my email via servlets, but it is not triggering. When I run code as a standalone Java application, it is working fine. Below is my code.
Servlet is giving me problem, from server I am not able to trigger the code

```
package model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
importjavax.naming.NamingException;

import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.CycleRecoverable.Context;

public class TestJavaMail   
{

    String userid ;
    String password;
    public TestJavaMail(String userid , String password)
    {
        this.userid = userid;
        this.password =password;
    }

        public void process()
        {

        String[] to = {"faiz.akhtar@agnitio-technologies.com","manish.kaushik@agnitio-           technologies.com",
                "sandeep.sharma@agnitio-technologies.com"};
        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.exchangemails.com");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", 25);   

        props.put("mail.smtp.user", userid);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.pass", password);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth ", "true");   

                                Authenticator auth = new javax.mail.Authenticator()   
        {   
             protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()   
            {   
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userid, password);   
            }   
        };   

                    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,auth);   

        try  
        {   
                                MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);   
            System.out.println("Mimemessage ceated");   
            InternetAddress[] iaFrom = { new InternetAddress(   
                    "moonis.raza@agnitio-technologies.com") };   
            msg.setFrom(iaFrom[0]);   
            InternetAddress[] iaTo =  new InternetAddress[to.length] ;  
            for(int i=0;i<to.length;i++)
            {
                iaTo[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, iaTo[i]);
            }

            msg.setSubject("Test Java Mail");   
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());   
            msg.setText("Hello, Congrats - It is working\n pls send acknowledgement mail to senderof u get this" +
                    "\n as it is part of project");   
            Transport tran = session.getTransport("smtp");   
            System.out.println("Transport object created......");   
            //tran.setStarttls(true);   
            tran.connect("smtp.exchangemails.com", 25, "moonis.raza@agnitio-           technologies.com", "welcome");   
            //tran.connect();   
            msg.saveChanges();   
            System.out.println("Connect succeeded");   
            tran.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());   
            tran.close();   
            System.out.println("Mail Sent Successfully");   
        }   
        catch (MessagingException mex)   
        {   
            System.out.println("send failed, exception: " + mex);   
        }   
                        }   
}
```

Here is servlet code:

```
package com.controller;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import model.TestJavaMail;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class emailservice
 */
   public class emailservice extends HttpServlet {


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws     ServletException, IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        System.out.println("here");

            PrintWriter writer = res.getWriter();
            writer.println("HELLO WORLD");
            String h = "hello";

            writer.println("" +h);

            writer.println("welcome ");

            writer.println(req.getRemoteHost());




        String userid = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("userid");
        String password = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("password");
        writer.println(userid);     
        TestJavaMail t1 = new TestJavaMail(userid, password);

        t1.process();
        writer.println("\n bhej di ");


    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

}
```

Comment: Large parts of your code seem to be commented out. Please improve the format of your code to make it more readable. And please trim it down to what is necessary to understand your problem.

Comment: can u tell me if me servlet code is ok to call the process() method.only i have commented my main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run you code for myself to see what would happen. First, I made sure I had `mail.jar` file available on the classpath. Second, I did a bit of necessary changes in order to be able to run the code without getting authentication errors. i.e, instead of:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.exchangemails.com");
```

I used:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

and obviously, I had to provide my own username and password for this different host.

You are right; The application worked well when was executed standalone. However, when I moved it to a `JBoss AS 7.0.0`, I encountered two different problems.

Initially, I faced this error:

```
at javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:320) [mail-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4]
at test.TestJavaMail.process(TestJavaMail.java:42) [classes:]
```

which after some googling and finding the solution given [here](http://www.java.net/node/697528), I could get rid of this error. i.e, I replaced this line:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
```

with:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
```

Then, I tried running the application again. This time, I received the below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/SSLPeerUnverifiedException
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    test.TestJavaMail.process(TestJavaMail.java:63)
```

I Googled the above error and found [there was a bug with my used JBoss version](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1278). So, I moved the application to a later `JBoss` version which was `JBoss AS 7.1.1` and I succeeded. The servlet successfully sent an email to the destination I had provided for it.

I hope this investigation will be helpful to you and to any visitor who is struggling with a similar problem.